# Backbone.js model property is getting not defined error

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm very new to Backbone.js and am trying to get this simple example working. Basically, in jsFiddle when I run the code it tells me that the property "firstname" is not defined.

Here's a link to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cpeele00/YjUBG/16/

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var UserList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: User
});

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $('#user-list ul'),
   template: _.template($('#user-list-template').html()),
   render: function() {
       this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
       return this;
   }
});

var user1 = new User();
user1.set({
   firstname: 'Momo',
   lastname: 'Peele'
});

var user2 = new User();
user2.set({
   firstname: 'Bobo',
   lastname: 'Peele'
});


var users = new UserList([user1, user2]);

var userView = new UserView({model: users});

userView.render();
```

​

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

V/R

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the model is actually a collection, you need to iterate over it, and apply the template to each model in the collection.  One way is to use the Underscore extension `Collection.each`:

```
render: function() {
    // clear the view
    this.$el.empty();

    // save a reference to the view object
    var self = this;

    // iterate over the collection
    this.model.each(function(singleModel) {

        // render the model
        self.$el.append(self.template(singleModel.toJSON()));
    });

    return this;
}
```

[Here's the updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Cep3Z/4/)

<sub>(You could also put the iteration into the template itself if you like, but I think it's generally preferable to keep code in the view, rather than the template.)</sub>